# Dynamic Variable Assignment and Typecasting in Abstract Class

Tags: flutter, dart, dynamic, casting, abstract-class

I'm trying to initialize a variable as a class object and further cast its type based on the parameter passed in the abstract class. However, since `as` in Dart doesn't accept conditional statement, the approach in the code is failing.

Here the variable is `c` in the code.

```
// Abscract class
abstract class MainTabs extends StatelessWidget {
    MainTabs(this.useIcon, {Key? key, required this.cls}) : super(key: key);
    
    final bool useIcon; 
    final String cls;
    
    // Content builder
    Widget contentBuilder(int index, Iterable? keys);
    
    // Issue in initializing the variable and casting it
    // Controller
    late final c = () {
        switch (cls) {
            case g.hotel:
                return HotelsController();
            case g.transport:
                return TransportController();
            default:
                return MonumentsController();
        }
    }() as (cls == g.hotel ? HotelsController : cls == g.transport ? TransportController : MonumentsController);
    // Issue here in the line above
    
    @override
    Widget build(BuildContext context) => useIcon
        ? iconView()
        : c.ifLoggedIn() ? limitedView(context) : fullView(context);
        
    ...
}


// Derived classes
class HotelsPage extends MainTabs {
    HotelsPage(useIcon, {Key? key}) : super(useIcon, key: key, cls: g.hotel);
    
    @override
    contentBuilder(int index, Iterable? keys) {
        ...
    }
}

class MonumentsPage extends MainTabs {
    MonumentsPage(useIcon, {Key? key}) : super(useIcon, key: key, cls: g.monuments);
    
    @override
    contentBuilder(int index, Iterable? keys) {
        ...
    }
}
```

How do I solve this issue? Additionally, my way isn't clean. Instead of a String (`cls`) and `switch` statement, I would like to pass the class object itself or as a function and proper casting.

Thanks

Comment: You can't specify a *static* (known at compile-time) type of a variable based on a *runtime* value.

Comment: Okay, so what is the nearest possible solution in that case or any alternative? Since the code isn't identifying the class methods and properties.

Comment: Why not just use `dynamic`?

Comment: When I use dynamic, Dart issues runtime error `Object.noSuchMethod` as it couldn't identify methods. However, when I perform explicit typecasting, it runs as expected. I can confirm, in either case, methods exist.

Comment: If you're getting `noSuchMethod` errors with `dynamic` but don't get any failures with explicit casts, then your code with casts is doing some additional checks that you didn't do with your `dynamic` version.

Comment: I understand. That's why I asked for a solution since I don't want to perform those checks else it would make the code cumbersome.